# GIT not working with Eclipse SVN - all repositories

Tags: eclipse, github, svn, repository

Since a few days ago, I have no access to GIT using Eclipse 3.8 and SVN 1.10

All was ok, but now I'm getting errors accessing ALL the GIT repositories!

> RA layer request failed
>   svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://github.com/eclipse/birt'
>   svn: Unexpected HTTP status 503 'Service Unavailable' on '/eclipse/birt'
>   svn: Additional errors:
>   svn: OPTIONS request on '/eclipse/birt' failed: 503 Service Unavailable

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: **This was a GIT PROBLEM... all is back to normal now... except https://github.com/eclipse/birt**

Comment: Today we have the same problem. Seems a github problem.

Comment: You are using the GitHub's [_Support for Subversion clients_](https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/), right? Maybe GitHub increased the key length. Which Java version do you use? If you do not use Java 8, does an update to Java 8 fix your problem?

Comment: We're using 8u152. But the problem can be reproduced with a local svn installation.

Comment: @Horcrux7, it was a GIT problem... so many hours lost on this one :\ All back to normal...

Comment: Still having problems with https://github.com/eclipse/birt

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know svn and git are not same thing, but they are very similar, but I could be wrong. Use git functionality, because form your output I see, that you try to use svn with github

Cheers

Comment: this answer does not answer the question. github has svn functionality which seems to be broken. sometimes svn has to be used instead of git - which ever reasons ...